# Bootstrap working on JSP but not when JSP is requested through servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap is working when I run a jsp  on it's own, but when I run my project (jsp goes to servlet and the servlet goes to another jsp through RequestDispatcher (which should use bootstrap styles) the bootstrap is no longer working.

I have downloaded bootstrap js and css files and have this in my jsp -

```
<link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src=../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Is there something else I need to do to make it work through the servlet?

Comment: @BalusC that doesnt particularly answer my question.. so am I supposed to put `href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" ` ? The answer to that question confused me quite a bit

Comment: import bootstrap from cdn

Comment: As explained in the duplicate, the `href` has to point to the URL of the bootstrap file, not to the disk file system path of the bootstrap file.